# Using HTML5 inputs in typo3

Tags: html, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

is it possible to user HTML5 inputs with type email and regex in TYPO3 fluid?

I've searched in doku but didn't finde something helpful.

Comment: Please post your expected HTML and what you currently get.

Comment: I want to do tis:

`<form>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="pattern" pattern="([S][S]|[W][S])[1-9]{2}"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>`

you can try expected behavour here:

http://jsfiddle.net/s82jan9o/#&togetherjs=5s6GtBsbzJ

Comment: This are two different input elements. Please edit your question by adding your current `fluid` attempt and the expected output.

Comment: Yes of course they are two different types. Excpected output is poated above js fiddle link. I can use normal html but then i cant build the object ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form>
  <f:form.textfield name="field-email" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
  <f:form.textfield name="field-pattern" pattern="([S][S]|[W][[1-9]{2}" placeholder="pattern" />
  <f:form.submit />
</form>
```

You might need to escape the pattern because the curly braces might be interpreted as `Fluid` syntax: `([S][S]|[W][[1-9]\{2\}`

Comment: You are right, in this case a custom viewhelper is needed. You just need extend form the original class and then to register the additional attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it :-).

The pattern attribute can be used with the form fields supporting it, according to the [source code](https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/HEAD:/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Form/TextfieldViewHelper.php).

The input types "email" and "url" are [documented](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Form/Textfield.html#eigenschaften-speziell-fur-diesen-viewhelper).

So yes: It works!

Comment: thanks, but type="email" dosn't work like the one of html5 

`<f:form.textfield name="email" type="email"`  ...


if you have a plain html5 input type="email" and you insert an email not corresponding to xyz@xyz.xyz the form won't be send ...